# Homework Problem: $\displaystyle{\sum^\infty_{n=0}\left(\frac{z^{n+1}}{n+1}-\frac{2z^{2n+3}}{2n+3}\right)}$ is discontinuous at $z=1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Prove: the complex series $\displaystyle{\sum^\infty_{n=0}\left(\frac{z^{n+1}}{n+1}-\frac{2z^{2n+3}}{2n+3}\right)}$ is discontinuous at $z=1$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What did you tried, Jihai?

Comment: @Nightflight I can only see that the series is convergent at $z=1$ and within the unit circle, but don’t know how to do any further

Comment: Why was this Q. downvoted?

Comment: @WlodAA Because the OP did not show any effort/attempt to solve the problem. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards

Comment: @Gary, are you serious or just joking? You can't be that stiff or r u?

Comment: @WlodAA I did not downvote the question and did not set up the quality standards either. However, I belive once we have them they should be enforced. This site is not to solve people's homeworks. Th OP has to give context to his/her question, give his/her thoughts on the problem and perhaps show his/her attempt(s) to solve it.

Comment: @Gary, "once we have them they should be enforced" -- I don't think so. All these insincere customs (ick!) should be abolished as fast as possible.

Comment: @WlodAA If you do not like how this site works just do not come here. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Gary, take it easy, man. I like mathematics, and you like all that garbage. Why don't you leave this place? Let people learn and enjoy mathematics, let's get rid of all this nonsense as "What did you tried, Jihai? " -- it's so offensive! (and poor English on the top of it :) ). Let's respect participants.

Comment: @WlodAA You have problems with the site's rules and I should leave? What's the logic behind that?

Comment: @Gary, rules don't have to stay forever, and when they are that poor they should be ignored. Let's change the rules or at least the practice.

Comment: @Gary, if u'r interested, I just started to write about the ***Art of Agreement*** (and knaB) again, you can be on my mailing list. My email is annarborwlod followed by "at" gmail.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $|z|<1$,

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
& \sum\frac{z^{n+1}}{n+1}-\frac{2z^{2n+3}}{2n+3}
= \sum\int t^n - 2t^{2n+2} \\
= &\int\sum t^n - 2t^{2n+2}
= \int\frac{1}{1-t} - \frac{2t^2}{1-t^2} \\
= & \int 2-\frac{1}{1+t} = 2z-\ln(1+z)=^{z\rightarrow1}2-\ln2
\end{split}
\end{equation}

For $z=1$,
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
& \sum\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{2}{2n+3}=2\sum\frac{1}{2n+2}-\frac{1}{2n+3}\\
= &2(1-\sum\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}) = 2(1-\ln2)=2-2\ln2\neq2-\ln2
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Hence the discontinuity.

Comment: Please do no not answer questions that do not meet the quality standards, see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards

Comment: @Gary Oh, now I know. Thank you.